# Oozie shell action using beeline

Tags: shell, hive, oozie, beeline

I am creating a oozie workflow in which I'm executing one she'll script. This shell script calls one ".hql" file using beeline.
The hql file is selecting from table one and inserting on table two, both the table one and two are partitioned.
When I am running Oozie job that beeline operation is executing with no error,but data is not getting inserted into table two.
The same hql command when I execute on beeline terminal works fine and inserts data in table two.
What could be possible reason for hql file not behaving as expected?

Comment: Where is your hql file ? did you validated that its been picked properly ? put set -x in the shell action script and check the stderr.

Comment: Oozie now has a `hive2` action that runs Beeline. Give it a try. Unless you really want to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: @roh Its in HDFS and yes i confirmed that its been correctly picked. I got the fixed mentioned below

Answer (score 0):

Read below article of horton work :
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/28224/strange-issue-with-beeline.html

After a lot of trial and error I found the issue. The hive.hql file was expecting a new line at the end of the query which is a bug in Hive 0.13.1 and has been fixed in hive 0.14.0.